# ein ganzzahliges Vielfache von

Tags: adjective, grammatical-number

this is a sentence in a textbook which said:

> Der Bahndrehimpuls L eines Elektrons ist ein ganzzahliges Vielfache von ...

Leaving aside the technical thing, I would like to know how `ein ganzzahliges Vielfache` works grammatically, as if we treat `vielfache` as an adjective, which seems incorrect because its ending should be consistent with `ganzzahliges`

Source: Physik Abitur - Basiswissen Schule - DUDEN

[image]

Comment: It is a typo / error. I has to read _ein ganzzahliges Vielfaches_.

Comment: I can haz t, pleaze?

Comment: @userunknown hmmm, what do u mean

Comment: @LeNguyen: "It has to read ..." - oder vielleicht aber auch "I have to read ...". Nicht wichtig, nur leicht kurios, einen Typo mit einem Typo (wenn es denn ein Typo war) zu kritisieren.

Comment: ganzzahliges Vielfaches = integer multiple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jonathan Scholbach already mentioned, there's a typo, it needs to be

> ... ein ganzzahliges Vielfaches von ...

In this case, "Vielfaches" is a noun, which would translate to "multiple", as in

> The second number was a multiple of the first.

In this case, it isn't just any multiple, but the factor has to be an [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer). In German, the set of integers ℤ is called the [ganze Zahlen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganze_Zahl), literally the "whole numbers" (because there's no fractional part).

So, a "ganzzahliges Vielfaches" is a multiple where the factor is an integer. The Bahndrehimpuls could, according to the quote in the question, for example be `2 * (h/2*pi)`, or `35 * (h/2*pi)`, or `-7 * (h/2*pi)`, but not `3.8 * (h/2*pi)`.